# How can I populate a combobox with Countries with arabic cultureInfo?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm trying to populate a `RadCombobox` with all countries but in Arabic language .

I have this code that I got from the web :

```
   public static List<string> CountryList()
    {
        List<string> CultureList = new List<string>();

        CultureInfo[] getCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

        foreach (CultureInfo getCulture in getCultureInfo)
        {
            RegionInfo GetRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(getCulture.LCID);
            

            if (!(CultureList.Contains(GetRegionInfo.EnglishName)))
            {
                CultureList.Add(GetRegionInfo.EnglishName);

            }
        }
        CultureList.Sort();
        return CultureList;
    }


        Countrycbx.ItemsSource = CountryList();
```

Xaml code:

```
      <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="Countrycbx" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
```

This code works perfectly in english format ( countries in english ) but I need to get them in Arabic .

**Result :**

[image]

**Expected result:**

```
الأرجنتين
ارمينيا
استراليا
النمسا
...
```

What can I change to make it works?

Comment: But what is going wrong?

Comment: I would like to get the countries names in Arabic not in English

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: But you get exactly what you've asked (GetRegionInfo.EnglishName). You should find lib or service to translate from en to Arabic

Comment: No I'm asked to translate it to Arabic , I would like to get names in Arabic

Comment: Your `CountryList()` method although informative, is not related to your problem. Your problem is how the Telerik combobox for WPF does display text. I have not used Telerik WPF, but this looks like a good start point [Telerik UI for WPF - Localization](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/common-information/common-localization)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "ArabicName" or other property than `EnglishName` available in .NET so you will have to provide the translations yourself.

I am afraid neither Microsoft's or Telerik's frameworks will help you out with this.

Comment: do you know any library can help for translate?

Comment: @csharp_devloper31: No. And SO is not the place to seek recommendations for libraries.